# Commerce - how to allow users to buy 2 free products

Tags: 7, commerce

For a current site I am building, authenticated users should be able to order 2 free products (of a certain type), after which the prices are back up to full price. Is there any solution which allows this kind of functionality? I can't seem to find the right words to search as nothing is coming up.

If not, any ideas on how to implement this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) / code?

I imagine I would have to add a new line item for the 2 free tickets at $0, and deduct these 2 products from the original line item, but I'm not sure at what stage in the process to do this. Any help?

Comment: You might be able to achieve something with [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) and give 100% discount on the first 2 products? I guess that would be easier than working with new line items.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer) you can have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module take care of "*monitoring users about buying their first 2 products*" (as in your question). The advantage of using the Goals module, is that you can keep track of all sorts of **events that are happening asynchronously** (which you cannot do by only using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and its events).

So with that it seems that your question (challenge) is reduced to finding a way to configure the appropriate set of **Goals** and related **Tasks**. For a basic introduction about [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals), have a look at:

- [How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)
- Its [video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/58425741).

Here is what it would take to implement something like a ***frequent buyers*** program:

1. **Goal** = "New customer", with only 1 **Task** = "Buy 1 product" (say with machine name = `buy_product`).
2. **Goal** = "Existing customer", with **Task** = "Buy 2 products".

The interesting part of this is that you'd only have to write 1 rule (related to that machine name = `buy_product`) to keep track of the progress of any user to become either a "new" or "existing" customer (check the video for a similar sample).

***Homework***: how should a rule look like to indicate that a user bought a product (either the very first one, or yet another one)?